# How can I combine elements of an array that are linear?

Tags: javascript, recursion

My data looks like:

```
[ [ '0s', '0.200s' ],
  [ '0.200s', '0.600s' ],
  [ '1.600s', '2.500s' ],
  [ '3.500s', '3.900s' ],
  [ '3.900s', '4.400s' ],
  [ '4.400s', '4.600s' ],
  [ '4.600s', '4.700s' ],
  [ '4.700s', '5.200s' ],
  [ '5.200s', '5.400s' ],
  [ '5.400s', '5.800s' ],
  [ '5.800s', '6.100s' ],
  [ '6.100s', '6.800s' ],
  [ '6.800s', '7s' ],
  [ '7s', '7.300s' ],
  [ '7.300s', '7.500s' ]
]
```

The first element ends at `0.200s` which is where the second element begins. So I want those 2 to combine to be `['0s', '0.600s']`.

The next element doesn't start where this one ends, so it should continue on. Ultimately, the result should look like:

```
[ [ '0s', '0.600s' ],
  [ '1.600s', '2.500s' ],
  [ '3.500s', '7.500s' ]
]
```

I am trying to do it recursively, but it's giving errors. Here's my function:

```
function combineStartsEnds(timecodes) {
  if (timecodes[0][1] === timecodes[1][0]) {
    let combined = [
      [timecodes[0][0], timecodes[1][1]]
    ].concat(_.slice(timecodes, 2));

    return combineStartsEnds(combined);
  } else {
    return timecodes[0].concat(combineStartsEnds(_.slice(timecodes, 1)));
  }
};
```

This gives an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing brackets here, this:

```
 return timecodes[0].concat(...)
```

must be:

```
 return [timecodes[0]].concat(...)
```

Additionally you need a base case to end the recursion:

```
 function combineStartsEnds(timecodes) {
   if(!timecodes.length) return [];
```

---

How I would do that:

```
 function combineStartsEnds(timecodes) {
   const result = []; let previous = [];
   for(const [start, end] of timecodes) {
     if(start === previous[/*end*/ 1]) {
       previous[/*end*/ 1] = end;
     } else {
       result.push(previous = [start, end]);
    }
  }
  return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `reduce`.

```js
const times = [ [ '0s', '0.200s' ],
  [ '0.200s', '0.600s' ],
  [ '1.600s', '2.500s' ],
  [ '3.500s', '3.900s' ],
  [ '3.900s', '4.400s' ],
  [ '4.400s', '4.600s' ],
  [ '4.600s', '4.700s' ],
  [ '4.700s', '5.200s' ],
  [ '5.200s', '5.400s' ],
  [ '5.400s', '5.800s' ],
  [ '5.800s', '6.100s' ],
  [ '6.100s', '6.800s' ],
  [ '6.800s', '7s' ],
  [ '7s', '7.300s' ],
  [ '7.300s', '7.500s' ]
];

const merged = times.reduce((acc, [t3, t4]) => {
  const [t1, t2] = acc[acc.length - 1] || [null, null];
  if (t2 === t3) {
    acc.pop();
    acc.push([t1, t4]);
  } else {
    acc.push([t3, t4]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below method to get your desired result.

(1) Flatten the array, you will get

```
arr.flat()

["0s", "0.200s", "0.200s", "0.600s", "1.600s", "2.500s", "3.500s", "3.900s", "3.900s", "4.400s", "4.400s", "4.600s", "4.600s", "4.700s", "4.700s", "5.200s", "5.200s", "5.400s", "5.400s", "5.800s", "5.800s", "6.100s", "6.100s", "6.800s", "6.800s", "7s", "7s", "7.300s", "7.300s", "7.500s"]
```

(2) Filter and remove elements if same exists before and after it's position, you will get

```
arr.flat().filter((d,i,c) => d != c[i-1] && d != c[i+1])

["0s", "0.600s", "1.600s", "2.500s", "3.500s", "7.500s"]
```

(3) Reduce the above result to the format you need

```
arr.flat()
    .filter((d,i,c) => d != c[i-1] && d != c[i+1])
    .reduce((res, d, i, c) => (i%2 == 0 && res.push([d, c[i+1]]) , res) , [])

[["0s", "0.600s"]
["1.600s", "2.500s"]
["3.500s", "7.500s"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `Map()`:

```
const data = [
    ['0s', '0.200s'],
    ['0.200s', '0.600s'],
    ['1.600s', '2.500s'],
    ['3.500s', '3.900s'],
    ['3.900s', '4.400s'],
    ['4.400s', '4.600s'],
    ['4.600s', '4.700s'],
    ['4.700s', '5.200s'],
    ['5.200s', '5.400s'],
    ['5.400s', '5.800s'],
    ['5.800s', '6.100s'],
    ['6.100s', '6.800s'],
    ['6.800s', '7s'],
    ['7s', '7.300s'],
    ['7.300s', '7.500s']
];

var data_map = new Map(data);

for (var [key, value] of data_map) {
    while (data_map.has(value)) {
        var new_value = data_map.get(value);
        data_map.set(key, new_value);
        data_map.delete(value);
        value = new_value;
    }
}

data_map.forEach((value, key) => console.log(`[${key}, ${value}]`));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array with a single loop by checking the values and update either the last array or push a new array to the result set.

```js
var data = [['0s', '0.200s'], ['0.200s', '0.600s'], ['1.600s', '2.500s'], ['3.500s', '3.900s'], ['3.900s', '4.400s'], ['4.400s', '4.600s'], ['4.600s', '4.700s'], ['4.700s', '5.200s'], ['5.200s', '5.400s'], ['5.400s', '5.800s'], ['5.800s', '6.100s'], ['6.100s', '6.800s'], ['6.800s', '7s'], ['7s', '7.300s'], ['7.300s', '7.500s']],
    combined = data.reduce((r, [a, b]) => {
        var last = r[r.length - 1];
        if (last && a === last[1]) {
            last[1] = b;
        } else {
            r.push([a, b]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(combined);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it using recursion –

```js
const start = ([ a, b ]) =>
  a

const end = ([ a, b ]) =>
  b

const join = ([ a, b, ...rest ]) =>
  // base: no `a`
  a === undefined
    ? []
  // inductive: some `a`  
  : b === undefined
    ? [ a ]
  // inductive: some `a` and some `b` (joinable)
  : end (a) === start (b)
    ? join ([ [ start (a), end (b) ], ...rest ])
  // inductive: some `a` and some `b` (non-joinable)
  : [ a, ...join ([ b, ...rest ]) ]

const data =
  [ [ '0s', '0.200s' ]
  , [ '0.200s', '0.600s' ]
  , [ '1.600s', '2.500s' ]
  , [ '3.500s', '3.900s' ]
  , [ '3.900s', '4.400s' ]
  , [ '4.400s', '4.600s' ]
  , [ '4.600s', '4.700s' ]
  , [ '4.700s', '5.200s' ]
  , [ '5.200s', '5.400s' ]
  , [ '5.400s', '5.800s' ]
  , [ '5.800s', '6.100s' ]
  , [ '6.100s', '6.800s' ]
  , [ '6.800s', '7s' ]
  , [ '7s', '7.300s' ]
  , [ '7.300s', '7.500s' ]
  ]

console.log (join (data))
// [ [ '0s', '0.600s' ]
// , [ '1.600s', '2.500s' ]
// , [ '3.500s', '7.500s' ]
// ]
```